# Как лучше сделать блюр в Canvas ?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Может кто сталкивался с таким кейсом или может есть какая то либа максимально приближенная к задаче ?

Нужна анимация на канвасе как в видео, я нашёл только [particle js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/)

Основная задача в том что надо блюрить какую то часть. 
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qkDl7GZ80E)